# bootstrap javascript runtime error object.keys argument is not an object

Tags: javascript, object, runtime

After getting latest of an entirely new solution, I'm getting a bootstrap javascript runtime error object.keys argument is not an object.

TFS 2013, VS 2015, and all security settings match my colleague's (who doesn't get the error).

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Is the solution stored in a version control system like git? After getting the project to your machine did you check to see if there were package requirements that needed to be installed?

Comment: TFS2013 is being used.  Local workspace cleared out completely before getting the latest of the solution.  Works for a colleague but I get the runtime error.  I'm wondering if I need a java reinstall ?

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue in bootstrap that gonna be fix in the next release 4.1.1

This is the link to track the issue.
[fix issue related to Object.keys and Dropdown issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/26291)